# updating a qt GUI with messages generated by a multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyside2

I’m trying to combine QThread and multiprocessing to be able to run some long processing task while keeping my GUI responsive and updated with the status of the process.

The following code does not update the label until the complete process is over, so I only see the last message. But the `print` works fine.

```
import time
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, QObject, Signal
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


class Worker():
    """Worker running in a Process"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.r0 = 2
        self.N = 10

    def setR0(self, r0):
        self.r0 = r0

    def setN(self, n):
        self.N = n

    def task(self, queue):
        for i in range(self.N):
            res = self.r0 ** i
            queue.put(str(i) + ": " + str(res))
            time.sleep(1)
        queue.put("done")


class Runner(QObject):
    """Runner is running in a qthread"""
    messageLogged = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def exec_(self):
        worker = Worker()
        worker.setN(15)
        worker.setR0(3)

        queue = Queue()

        process = Process(target=worker.task, args=(queue,))
        process.start()

        while True:
            msg = queue.get()
            if msg == "done":
                self.messageLogged.emit("received 'done' signal")
                break
            self.messageLogged.emit(msg)

        process.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    widget.setLayout(layout)

    button = QPushButton("Run")
    layout.addWidget(button)

    label = QLabel("initial text")
    layout.addWidget(label)

    thread = QThread()
    r = Runner()
    r.messageLogged.connect(print)
    r.messageLogged.connect(label.setText)
    thread.started.connect(r.exec_)

    def onButtonPushed():
        thread.start()
        button.setEnabled(False)

    button.clicked.connect(onButtonPushed)

    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

What am I missing in order to keep the interface responsive ?
I have a feeling that my listener loop should also be a `Process`, but then how do I emit a signal that can be connect to my label?

Comment: adding a `QCoreApplication.instance().processEvents()` after emitting the signal helpswith the issue of the label update, But not with the application responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by removing the QThread and using a QTimer instead. The timer reads all messages in the queue at a regular interval, and then lets the GUI be responsive again for a while, until next timeout.

```
import time

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtCore import QTimer
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


class Worker():
    """Worker running in a Process"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.r0 = 2
        self.N = 10

    def setR0(self, r0):
        self.r0 = r0

    def setN(self, n):
        self.N = n

    def task(self, queue):
        for i in range(self.N):
            res = self.r0 ** i
            queue.put(str(i) + ": " + str(res))
            time.sleep(1)
            print(i)
        queue.put("done")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    widget.setLayout(layout)

    button = QPushButton("Run")
    layout.addWidget(button)

    label = QLabel("initial text")
    layout.addWidget(label)

    button2 = QPushButton("Kill")
    button2.setEnabled(False)
    layout.addWidget(button2)

    queue = Queue()
    worker = Worker()
    worker.setN(15)
    worker.setR0(3)

    process = Process(target=worker.task, args=(queue, ))

    def read():
        while not queue.empty():
            msg = queue.get()
            if msg == "done":
                label.setText("received 'done' signal")
            else:
                label.setText(msg)

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(read)

    def onRunButtonPushed():
        print("run clicked")
        process.start()
        timer.start(1000)
        button.setEnabled(False)
        button2.setEnabled(True)

    def onKillButtonPushed():
        process.terminate()
        timer.stop()

    button.clicked.connect(onRunButtonPushed)
    button2.clicked.connect(onKillButtonPushed)

    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```